# Survival analysis output interpretation

Tags: survival, interpretation

I have two questions on survival analysis I was hoping some clever people on this forum could help answer for me!

(1) In Cox proportional hazards model, if you add one variable onto the model (going from univariate to multivariate analysis), and the original covariate becomes less statistically significant, i.e. experienced an increase in p-value as well as a wider CI, why is this the case?

(2) Now, if the two covariates are both statistically significantly associated with the outcome, what can we say about the nature of the relationship between them?

I look forward to your insights!

KA

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a statistician, but a molecular biologist trying to learn more about stats. Here are my two cents:

1) This sounds like two variables are correlated. So when you adjust for one variable (ie. discounting the effects of that particular variable), the second variable has less of an impact on the survival. Consider the following: you are looking at the effects of a gene and gender on survival in a dataset where females express higher levels of the gene and also have shorter survival times. You would expect statistical significance with each of the variables in a univariate analysis. But, when you adjust for gender, having higher levels of the gene is not associated with the survival outcome (i.e. reduction in p values)

2) I don't think it says much about the exact relationship between the variables. Such a result would mean that both variables have some impact on the survival independently from one another.